# Page resizing using cappuccino

Tags: window-resize, autoscroll, cappuccino, objective-j

How can I increase my window size when dragging an object in the window, after it's bounds using cappuccino. Here is my sample code:

```
if(dragLocation.x < 1000.0 && dragLocation.y < 600.0)  {

    //drag is within the drawable area
    [self setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake(dragLocation.x, dragLocation.y)];    
    dragLocation = location;        
}

else   {
      //object is dragged out of window
      // the window has to be resized now
      //how????
}
```

The problem is like, when I drag an object out of my window it is disappearing. I want it to be appear by enlarging the window. How can I do that in cappuccino. Any suggestions would be helpful.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about a platform window (the whole browser window) or an individual app window inside of a larger browser window? You can change window sizes with `[window setFrameSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]`, but if it's a platform window the browser might not allow the window size change.

Comment: I am not getting how to add resizing points to a shape. I have added the shape to a view. Any idea? thaks

Comment: Normally you'd overlay another view and draw resizing handles using its `drawRect:` method.